# Silex autoload my namespace

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, silex

The site is using Silex.

Structure look like this:

```
root
  api
    RSYWX
      Book.php
  vendor
  views
  web
```

In `Book.php`:

```
namespace RSYWX;

class Book {
  public static function sayHello() 
  {
      return "Hello, there!";
  }
}
```

In `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "twig/twig": "^1.23",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^2.7"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "RSYWX\\": "/api/RSYWX"
      }
  }
}
```

I ran `composer update` to update the autoload relevant files, in particular the 
`vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`:

```
return array( 
  ...
  'RSYWX\\' => array('/api/RSYWX'), 
  ...
```

When I tried to call `sayHello` from `index.php` file, the error log has this line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RSYWX\\Book' not found in vagrant/api.rsywx.com/web/index.php on line 32
```

Any hints to load this class and the static method?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
"RSYWX\\": "api/RSYWX"
```

Because using `/` on beginning refers to server's root directory and it's probably not what you wanted. Of course call `composer update` after changing `composer.json` file.

Comment: in that case `composer dump-autoload` is enough